# Unable to call method from for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, listview

I have an issue that is strange to me (being new to Objective-C), but probably obvious to the experts.

So I have a ViewController with a method that will add items to a NSMutableArray which is linked to a ListView. The idea is that it will populate by calling a WebService URL using AFNetworking.

The NSMutable array is defined like this:

```
@property NSMutableArray *newsItems;
```

I then made a method that adds an object to the array:

```
- (void)addNewsItemWithId:(NSInteger)newsId withMessage:(NSString *)message withDate:(NSString *)date {
    SCWNewsItem *item = [[SCWNewsItem alloc] init];
    item.id = newsId;
    item.date = date;
    item.preview = message;
    [self.newsItems addObject:item];
}
```

Then I have another method called `loadInitialData` which will load the data into the array.

If I test it like this:

```
- (void)loadInitialData {
    [self addNewsItemWithId:1 withMessage:@"A first message" withDate:@"2014-04-17"];
    [self addNewsItemWithId:2 withMessage:@"A second message" withDate:@"2014-04-17"];
}
```

It will work fine. I can run and view the two messages in my ListView.

However if I try to do this, it doesn't add anything:

```
- (void)loadInitialData {

    NSLog(@"URL: %@", URL_GET_NEWS_ITEMS);

    NSString *token = scwData.authToken;
    if (token == nil) {
        [self returnToLogin];
    }
    else {
        AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        [manager.requestSerializer setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Token %@", token] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

        [manager GET:URL_GET_NEWS_ITEMS parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            for (NSDictionary *arr in responseObject) {
                NSInteger itemId = [[arr valueForKey:@"id"] intValue];
                NSString *name = [arr valueForKey:@"author_name"];
                NSString *date = [arr valueForKeyPath:@"date_posted"];
                NSString *message = [arr valueForKey:@"message"];

                NSLog(@"itemId: %i", itemId); 

                [self addNewsItemWithId:itemId withMessage:message withDate:date];
            }

        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Failed: %@", operation.responseObject);
        }];
    }
}
```

I can see from using NSLog that the loop is definitely being iterated and each attribute in the JSON array is being outputted to my log, however it just won't add any items to my ListView.

Really appreciate if someone could educate me as to what is happening here.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Did you allocate the `newsItems` array ?

Comment: Do you call `reloadData` for tableView object after receiving data?

Comment: What is a ListView? If you are using a UITableView - what logic will refresh it to reload the current content of your array?

Answer (score 1):

Have you initialized self.newsItems
like
self.newsItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
in viewDidLoad or you may try in loadInitialData too.
Please check
Other things looks good. Hope this helps.
Let me know the output array or array count.

Answer (score 0):

Create a mutable array.

```
- (void)loadInitialData {
   self.newsItems = [NSMutableArray new];
   //Rest of your code here
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this and it still didn't work. Also it wouldn't make sense considering it works if I call the addNewsItemWithId method outside of the web service response, it works fine.

Comment: check your responseObject. See it it's an array of dictionaries. Do you see this log NSLog(@"itemId: %i", itemId); in console ?